# $elemmatch not working in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to filter mongo data by using the below query in mongodb version 2.6.1 but getting error.

MongoDB version 2.4.6 (Working):

```js
> db.BC_1839.find({data: {$elemMatch:{$where : "this.First_name.toLowerCase().indexOf('kim') ==0"}}});
```

output:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("53719a9d5b9e5c8c110001b9"),
    "data" : [
        {
            "First_name" : "Kimberely",
            "Last_name" : "Weyman",
            "Company_name" : "Scientific Agrcltl Svc Inc",  
            "Address" : "7721 Harrison St",
            "City" : "Kingsway West",
            "State" : "NS",
            "Post" : "2208",   
            "Phone1" : "02-7091-8948",   
            "Phone2" : "0441-151-810", 
            "Email" : "kweyman@weyman.com.au",
            "Web" : "http://www.scientificagrcltlsvcinc.com.au", 
            "active" : "true"
        } 
    ], 
    "history" : [    
        { 
            "timestamp" : "2014-05-13 06:07:55",
            "event": "creation",
            "createdby" : "Srikesh Infotech",
            "creation_data" : [
                {
                    "crm_base_contact_id" : "1839",
                    "crm_imported_files_id" : "1464"
                }  
            ] 
        },
        {
            "timestamp" : "2014-05-13 06:09:05",
            "event" : "Task",
            "createdby" : "Srikesh Infotech",
            "Task_data" : [ 
                {
                    "Campaign ID" : "193",  
                    "Campagin Name" : "Test Campa1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "ref" : [ 
        { "crm_base_contact_id" : "1839", "crm_imported_files_id" : "1464" }
    ]
}
```

MongoDB version 2.6.1(Not Working):

```js
> db.BC_1839.find({data: {$elemMatch:{$where : "this.First_name.toLowerCase().indexOf('kim') ==0"}}});
```

output:

```js
error: {
        "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $elemMatch cannot contain $
where expression",
        "code" : 17287
}
```

Same query executes in mongodb version 2.4.6 but not in mongodb version 2.6.1 Why???

Comment: possible duplicate of [$Where -- Not working in Mongo PHP Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730647/where-not-working-in-mongo-php-code)

Comment: Please do not post the same question just because your previous question does not have an answer as yet.

Comment: can you explain why the same query not executing different MongoDB versions????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't have worked in earlier versions at all, as at the very least you have modified the scoping of `this` to now refer to "data" as a top level element. In short, this is no longer allowed and you really should not be using JavaScript methods unless you absolutely have to. Even then, there is probably still a better way in most cases.

But in fact this is an un-necessary use of JavaScript matching as it is not required when there are other operators existing that will do this.

You should be using a [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) form instead:

```js
db.docs.find({ "data.First_name": /^kim/i })
```

Or anywhere within the field, remove the caret `^`:

```
db.docs.find({ "data.First_name": /kim/i })
```

Which is pretty much as inefficient as JavaScript execution but not as much as there is not the overhead of processing through that interpreter engine. And of course it works everywhere.

Also think about what a query relying on JavaScript to resolve is actually doing:

- Invokes a JavaScript interpreter instance
- Converts BSON document types per document to JavaScript types
- Evaluates JavaScript code in the interpreter per document
- Casts JavaScript `true|false` back as a result per document

Considering that [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) ( but with a case insensitive match which is not optimal ) is doing the same operations but using the "pcre" C library natively without conversion and recasting per document, then it is clearly the sane choice of the two.

Comment: Can you give me the regex for "does not startswith" ?

Comment: @Manadh remove the `^` caret. That is what anchors to the starting position of the string. It generally makes things more efficient, but the way MongoDB indexing ( which is case sensitive ) works the general query must at least scan the index to find case insensitive matches. But that and the other reasons given make it better than JavaScript, which has the other overheads and would be a collection scan.

Comment: @Manadh So does this work for you now without breaking across versions? Acceptance would be nice :)

Comment: I have installed mongo in two system , one system has 2.4.6 and another system has latest version 2.6.1, above $where condition query works in older version but throws error in new version "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $elemMatch cannot contain $
where expression", @Neil Lunn , Actually "starts with" alone not enough i have criteria with lot contitions using AND , OR logic . I have substitute values and filter those criteria from mongo. I have worked on this using "JS" and worked fine so far. Can you please say me why this not working in 2.6.1 version ?

Comment: @Manadh Is the error itself not enough? There is a documentation patch that is required yes [SERVER-140010](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14010) But you really should not be using JS anyway. Not starting with was answered several comments ago if you read them

Comment: @Niel Lunn.Thank you. Can you give me any idea how to form query  like this, ((A and B) or C) this my filter condition, for A i substitute  value say "First_name starts with 'Kim'" for "B" say "Last_name endswith "ly" and for "C" say "Age > 30".. how to form query for this condition  using PHP and apply to mongo to filter result ?